# How can I measure the bit rate at which my postgres database is sending out data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, macos, networking

I am working on trying to speed up a bottleneck in which the limiting factor appears to be the rate at which data is fetched from a PostgreSQL database for a particular query. The query is pretty basic, essentially the following:

```
SELECT id, metadata1, metadata2, data FROM tablename WHERE id IN <list of several thousand IDs> ORDER BY id;
```

in which the data field is a JSONB containing lots and lots of data. Each row contains JSON in this field that, when uncompressed, averages around 10,000 characters. This query takes a very long time to extract the data.

There are three areas I'm looking into: query optimization (which isn't bearing much fruit), further compressing the data (more promising), and potential networking issues. By my rough back of the envelope calculation, the data is going at around 100 megabits per second. I would expect that today's hardware would be capable of doing this at a much faster bitrate. I'm using a new Macbook Pro with the M1 chip.

The postgres database is on one port, and it's talking to python code running on another port. I am looking specifically for a tool that lets me look at the flow of data from the one port to the other, and measure the bitrate. I have found some queries to look at the size of the objects within postgres itself, but since JSONB is compressed and the compression takes place within postgres, this isn't a particularly useful measure. Also, much of what I am finding focuses on TPS, which is not what I am looking for either. I have also found some ways in python to measure the size of the objects themselves, but again, there are data conversion issues and I'd much rather measure the data bitrate directly midstream. I want to be able to either rule out network issues as the bottleneck, or identify the issue so I can resolve it. I am looking for a tool I can run that does what I am describing. I strongly prefer a tool that runs in the MacOS shell, but one that runs in PostgresQL or Python 3.9 is also acceptable so long as it actually measures the bitrate directly one way or another.

As described above, I used a variety of queries and tools in Postgres on the one end and Python3.9 on the other, but they have given inconsistent and questionably accurate/useful results. Google searches have given me loads of results that aren't particularly applicable.

Comment: The important part missing from the above is defining "This query takes a very long time to extract the data.". Where are you measuring the time that leads you to this conclusion?

Comment: You say you measured it at 100Mb/s, so it seems like you got your answer yourself.  What more is there to ask?  Yes, that seems pretty slow, but you also mention "maybe networking" which implies that a network is in use (rather than just localhost).  That is not the best way to optimize throughput, so do change it to run both processes on the same host and see if that changes things.

Comment: @jjanes no, it's not a measurement. It's a very rough back of the envelope estimate. As for the network topology, it's two different ports on localhost. I am looking to directly measure the rate at which bits are flowing between those two ports.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I've verified this both within the python code itself and within the PgAdmin query tool.

Comment: Exactly how you are doing the measuring would be useful to know. For one displaying the data in pgAdmin is going to be slow for any large numbers of values as rendering  the GUI widgets is a slow process.